# K-fold cross validation modification to generated ANN code?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

My data set is basically a matrix of 3 variables (input), and a matrix of 1 variable (target). There are 50 total data sets for each of these (basically 50 samples of f(x,y,z) = t)

I have only done the ANN training using the GUI. Never really with the script/code.

My most simple objective now is to split the data manually for each train-test run, so I can just painstakingly run the neural network 5 times, but I'm not even sure how to manually select a range of the data set for use in training, and which one for testing.

Here's the full exported script from MATLAB. The point of focus is shown below the wall of code.

```
% Solve an Input-Output Fitting problem with a Neural Network
% Script generated by NFTOOL
% Created Mon Jul 17 02:39:31 SGT 2017
%
% This script assumes these variables are defined:
%
%   DEinp - input data.
%   DEcgl - target data.

inputs = DEinp;
targets = DEcgl;

% Create a Fitting Network
hiddenLayerSize = 10;
net = fitnet(hiddenLayerSize);

% Choose Input and Output Pre/Post-Processing Functions
% For a list of all processing functions type: help nnprocess
net.inputs{1}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};
net.outputs{2}.processFcns = {'removeconstantrows','mapminmax'};


% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% For help on training function 'trainlm' type: help trainlm
% For a list of all training functions type: help nntrain
net.trainFcn = 'trainlm';  % Levenberg-Marquardt

% Choose a Performance Function
% For a list of all performance functions type: help nnperformance
net.performFcn = 'mse';  % Mean squared error

% Choose Plot Functions
% For a list of all plot functions type: help nnplot
net.plotFcns = {'plotperform','plottrainstate','ploterrhist', ...
  'plotregression', 'plotfit'};


% Train the Network
[net,tr] = train(net,inputs,targets);

% Test the Network
outputs = net(inputs);
errors = gsubtract(targets,outputs);
performance = perform(net,targets,outputs)

% Recalculate Training, Validation and Test Performance
trainTargets = targets .* tr.trainMask{1};
valTargets = targets  .* tr.valMask{1};
testTargets = targets  .* tr.testMask{1};
trainPerformance = perform(net,trainTargets,outputs)
valPerformance = perform(net,valTargets,outputs)
testPerformance = perform(net,testTargets,outputs)

% View the Network
view(net)

% Plots
% Uncomment these lines to enable various plots.
%figure, plotperform(tr)
%figure, plottrainstate(tr)
%figure, plotfit(net,inputs,targets)
%figure, plotregression(targets,outputs)
%figure, ploterrhist(errors)
```

I figured that all I needed to do was mess with the net.divideMode section, but I really have no idea how to change the syntax to complete my objective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Network Parameters

The process of splitting the data into training, validation and test sets happens in the section that you identified. I'm just going to break down each of the lines. Starting with:

```
% Setup Division of Data for Training, Validation, Testing
% For a list of all data division functions type: help nndivide
net.divideMode = 'sample';  % Divide up every sample
```

The divideMode is well documented in [Neural Network Object Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/neural-network-object-properties.html)

> **net.divideMode**
>
> This property defines the target data dimensions which
>   to divide up when the data division function is called. Its default
>   value is 'sample' for static networks and 'time' for dynamic networks.
>   It may also be set to 'sampletime' to divide targets by both sample
>   and timestep, 'all' to divide up targets by every scalar value, or
>   'none' to not divide up data at all (in which case all data is used
>   for training, none for validation or testing).

So your network is a static network which divides up every sample into a training example. This will remain the same for your cross-validation. What you are interested in manipulating is the training, test, and validation splits.

```
net.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
net.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
net.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;
```

Okay, the variable names here seem promising, but you want a little more control than just choosing the ratio size.

Again the [Neural Network Object Properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ug/neural-network-object-properties.html) point us towards more information

> **net.divideParam**
>
> This property defines the parameters and values of the current
>   data-division function. To get a description of what each field means,
>   type the following command:
>
> `help(net.divideFcn)`

This will print out information about how your dataset is partitioned into training, validation, and test splits. In your current configuration, the message reads

> **dividerand** Partition indices into three sets using random indices.
>
> `[trainInd,valInd,testInd] = dividerand(Q,trainRatio,valRatio,testRatio)`   takes a number of
>   samples Q and divides up the sample indices 1:Q   between training,
>   validation and test indices.
>
> **dividerand** randomly assigns sample indices to the three sets according   to the three ratios.
>
> (...)
>
> See also divideblock, divideind, divideint, dividetrain.

Since you want more control of the partitions, you should check out these additional options.

I think the most promising is [`divideind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/nnet/ref/divideind.html). This option allows you to specify the indices for each partition. You can calculate the indices for each fold in your k-fold cross validation and reassign the partitions in each iteration using this option.

To set this parameter, replace the `net.divideParam` lines above with something like,

```
net.divideFcn = 'divideind';
net.divideParam.Q = length(targets); %This is the total number of instances in your data 
net.divideParam.trainInd = your_train_ind;
net.divideParam.valInd = your_val_ind;
net.divideParam.testInd = your_test_ind;
```

### K-folds

Last detail, how to select the indices? First, a quick review on k-fold cross-validation.

1. The data is split into k equally sized subsamples.
2. In each iteration of cross-validation, we train on k-1 of the subsamples and test on the remaining subsamples, rotating to a new testing subsamples each time.

An implementation sketch might look like this

```
k = 5; % As an example, let's let k = 5
sample_size = length(targets)/k;

%Make a vector of all the indices of your data from 1 to the total number of instances
indices= 1:length(targets); 

% Optional: Randomize samples
indices = randperm(length(targets));

% Iterate in steps of sample_size
for ii = 1: sample_size:length(targets) - sample_size

    % Grab one subsample of indices for testing
    your_test_ind = indices( ii:ii + sample_size - 1);

    % Everything else
    your_train_ind = indices( [1:ii, ii + sample_size:end]);

    %Train and test your network here!
end
```

This is just an implementation sketch and **doesn't handle some edge cases correctly**. For example, the first element is always added to the training set, but it should be enough to get you started.

Comment: So uh... let's say I want to run a k of 5, making it 40/50 for training, and 10/50 for testing (keeping it simple, we won't use any for validation). How would my code look like? Assume my input var is just x, and target is y. I honestly did try to wrap my head around the different divide commands, but they were rather unresponsive to me during my attempts. I assume at least, it will be something like 

`net.divideFcn = 'divideind';`
`net.divideParam.x = 5(50);`
`net.divideParam.trainInd = 11:40; `
`net.divideParam.testInd = 1:10;`

I just have no idea what the length(target) is.

Comment: I've updated my answer. `length(target)` is the number of elements in the variable `target`.

Comment: Wow, commented code! Will give it a shot. Hope things run OK. Will get back to you in a few. Just curious, what if I have 53 data sets? I wonder how non-divisibles are handled by matlab in such a case?

Comment: Just tried it. Ended up quite wonky... the line `your_test_ind = indices( ii:ii+ sample_size );` was an error. Reason was "Index exceeds matrix dimensions."

I did ask this question to another stranger, but he couldn't help me solely because it's in matlab. Really appreciate your effort, but I'll keep trying my best with what you left me. If possible, a non-scalable version of the code would be much better. I'll just manually replace the parameters and run it multiple times. I'm going to save the results on different .m files anyway.

Comment: Sorry, didn't actually run the code on my end. That's an off by one error. I've edited to remove that error, but my implementation is just a sketch. You'll need to add some more logic for edge cases. Do you know how to use the [matlab debugger](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/debugging-process-and-features.html)? It's super useful.

Comment: I don't know how to use a debugger in general, but I will have to learn if I'm going to be programming in MATLAB to get all my work done.

Also, that change DID IT. IT RUNS NOW. What's fascinating is that even with the randomizer disabled, it kept giving different performance results!

That's a bit intriguing to me though...for a k-fold result, it's supposed to iterate 5 times, and produce 5 networks, giving me 5 different records of performance and MSE. The feeling that I'm getting here is that it actually TRAINED the network 5 times. Should I just get rid of the for loop in this case?1/1

Comment: The extremely low testing performances also seem to corroborate with my guess. That's my main reason for wanting a non-scalable version of it, but it's great to have a working baseline code for this. For that alone I'm grateful.2/2

Comment: Glad it worked. Do you mean that it trained the same network 5 times instead of training 5 different networks? You might need to reinitialize your network inside the for-loop. If you still get random results, it might be worth asking a new question.

Comment: Yeah, I just need to probably work on a labeling part.

The indentation didn't properly include the entire training process just now. But after properly arranged, it did indeed run 5 times! A worthwhile learning experience, this has been. I will probably tear apart the code just to make it run once.

Comment: Yo uh, there's some extremely funky stuff going on. [This](https://a.uguu.se/N8TP8ZiCBaT2_MATLAB_2017-08-29_09-06-41.png) is what I'm getting after doing a `net.divideParam.trainInd = 1:20, 31:53;`
and `net.divideParam.testInd = 21:30;` split of testing. Honestly, this graph doesn't make sense not only on the numbers (1.973/2 = 0.628???) but also graphically. Some of the stray dotted points from the overall graph are NOWHERE to be seen in the training and testing graphs. I also got WAY too many R=1 in the trainings. It feels like this code... is not a correct implementation of MATLAB k-fold.

Comment: What I feel that's wrongly executed by matlab here is the whole acknowledgement that it's trying to solve a curve fitting problem with 3input and 1target. I have no idea what it's doing, but it doesn't feel like it's doing that. So before I can proceed with this, I think I'll look into an alternative in python or something, with the keras package.